# How to find the class from html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some javascript code to remove html tags and content from a string of text but keep the class.
For example `<div class="my class"></div>` would return `myclass`
I've tried:

```
var x = "<div class='myClass'></div>";
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] == "<" ||
        x[i] == ">" ||
        x[i] == " " ||
        x[i] == "div")
            x[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: try something like `$(x).attr("class")`

Comment: Can the string ever contain any other elements? What should `<div class='myClass'></div><div class='myClass2'></div>` return, an array, or `myClassmyClass2` or what?

Comment: Also note that strings are immutable, you can't assign to individual indicies like that.

Comment: What is the expected output for `<div class='myClass'></div> <div class='myClass2'><div class='myClass3'><span class="myClass4"></span></div></div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a jquery line and you're all set... See below

```
$(x).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log($('div').attr('class').replace(' ', ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my class"></div>
```